# '_COOKIE_KEY_' ?How should I deal with the user authentication, or in general, the security issues on my Prestashop website?

Tags: security, primary-key, md5, prestashop-1.6

currently I am doing some development on my own Prestashop website.

When I wanted to add some user authentication mechanism to my project, I find some "key"s of the website in the file named `settings.inc.php`.

There is a key named `_COOKIE_KEY_` which is used to encrypt user's password and other information using MD5 encryption.

I am just wondering, if `_COOKIE_KEY_` a very primate key, or, it is a public key and it doesn't matter anyone else would see that? Please if anyone knows about it a little, I will be very grateful for the help. 
Thanks a million!

Comment: [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. Hashing is one way, whereas encryption is two way.

Answer (score 0):

This key is used to salt Customer Passwords in Database. It should remain confidential at all cost!

Here is the encryption function used to store password from class `classes/Tools.php`:

```php
/**
* Encrypt password
*
* @param string $passwd String to encrypt
*/
public static function encrypt($passwd)
{
    return md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd);
}
```